# Highlighting TableViewCell immediately

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a tableView cells without buttons. For this purpose I use UITableViewDelegate:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES animated:NO];
}
```

But I have a problem: there is a second delay between touch down and the highlighted state appearing. How can I implement the highlight appear immediately on touch down without the delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should uncheck delaysContentTouches property of TAbleView on IB. Or uncheck  programmatically:

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```